# iOS Sourcery with Flutter build

Tags: ios, sourcery

Im trying to build my flutter app for iOS it has a google maps key that I want to protect and not check in to source control it needs to be buildable from azure, to achieve this I'm storing my maps key as a secret variable in azure and as a system environment variable locally, I'm using Sourcery https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery to generate a class for me that contains this key, it all works but only the second time I build, the first build always fails.

So I'm building using this command

```
flutter build ios --flavor dev --verbose
```

Which the first run will give me the error

```
 error: Build input file cannot be found:
           '/Users/martin/xxx/xxx/xxx/ios/Runner/Credentials.generated.swift' (in target
```

'Runner'

Then issuing the same command again

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

this is my run script its called before compile sources and after the flutter run script

[image: run script]

this calls my script which calls another script to export the map api key and runs sourcery command using a .yml file as its config heres the script, (it also does some logging)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Generate Credentials Code"
CREDENTIALS_DIR="$SRCROOT/credentials"

# Set credentials if local script for adding environment variables exist
if [ -f "$CREDENTIALS_DIR/add_credentials_to_env.sh" ]; then
  echo "Add credentials to environement"
  source "$CREDENTIALS_DIR/add_credentials_to_env.sh"
  echo "finished running add_credentials_to_env.sh"
fi

echo "RUN SOURCERY"

$SRCROOT/Pods/Sourcery/bin/sourcery --config "$SRCROOT/config.yml" 
echo "FINISHED RUNNING SOURCERY"

for file in "$SRCROOT/Runner"/*; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

and here is my config file

```
sources:
  - .
project:
  file: Runner.xcodeproj
  target:
    name: Runner
    module: Runner
templates:
  - credentials/Credentials.stencil
output:
  path: ./Runner/
  link:
    project: Runner.xcodeproj
    target: Runner

args:
  mapsApiKey: ${MAPS_API_KEY_IOS}
```

this generates my class correctly on the first build and seems to be added correctly to the target (edited out my key) but the app will only compile if I run the build command again.

```
// Generated using Sourcery 1.4.2 — https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery
// DO NOT EDIT
public struct Credentials {
    let mapsApiKey: String
}
public let credentials = Credentials(mapsApiKey: 
"xxxxxxxxxxMY_KEYxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Any ideas?

xcode 12.5 m1 macbook pro, swift 5

Comment: Can you share the entire build phases section. Xcode **might** be re-ordering them if `"Parallelize Build"` is enabled (which is enabled by default). Disabling this may slow down your build time, but may fix the problem (you could try it). I have written an answer with better way of securing your keys though. You can try disabling it [here](https://i.imgur.com/uPNrZrL.png).

Comment: @BenButterworth i tried this but no joy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you generate the file too late. I'll suggest move your script to Aggregate and add it as a dependency to your target

1. Add Aggregate

[image: List item]

[image]

2. Move your script to 'Run script' section

[image]

3. Add 'PreBuildScriptsRunner' as a dependency to your application target, make sure 'Dependencies' section on top of all other sections

[image]

Comment: i will try this but i have a new problem to tackle soon as i do ill get back to you many thanks for your help

Comment: finally got around to this seems to work great many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting environment variables is an annoying thing developers would have to do on their own machines, and there are nicer/ more common ways of setting up private keys. After a few years of using environment variables/ bash, it still causes issues which are not easily detectable. You may want to automate/ document it, but then you have to consider developers using `zsh`, `fish` vs. `bash`? Also, I try to avoid using Xcode build phases where possible.

## Solution? (This is what I have)

Why don't you use your CI (Azure pipeline?, I use Github workflows) to write a Xcode build configuration file (not a Swift file). The sensitive keys could be in a file `Secrets.xcconfig`, which is added to your Xcode as a build configuration. Then, in your `Info.plist` of your application,  and your code can load them.

### Create a file, `Secrets.xcconfig`:

```
SECRET_API_KEY = 12312rfiwhvde.wvascafsf.df325
```

Add it to your Xcode project, and then to the project's build configuration:

[image: Xcode project info tab > configuration drop down]

### Add `Secrets.xcconfig` to your `.gitignore`

Make sure to git ignore the file before committing it to the repo. You can also keep an `Example.Secrets.xcconfig` which users can use. In the readme, tell users to run `cp Example.Secrets.xcconfig Secrets.xcconfig` and then to update values in it. Now you can clearly see what keys the application is using (its clearly in the directory). As a bonus, you can add this file the Xcode project, so that when the file is missing, it shows up in red (indicating to the user they really should acquire this file somehow):

[image: Red font for Secrets.xcconfig]

### In Info.plist, reference the variable:

```
<dict>
    <key>SECRET_API_KEY</key>
    <string>$(SECRET_API_KEY)</string>
</dict>
```

### In your code, load the variable that was stored in `Info.plist`:

```swift
let key = Environment.infoDictionary["SECRET_API_KEY"] as? String
```

### In your CI/ Azure pipeline:

Run `echo "SECRET_API_KEY = $SECRET_API_KEY_SAVED_IN_CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION" >> Secrets.xcconfig`

Then you can just `.gitignore` the file instead of setting environment variables. When you work with other developers, you just give them this file, and nothing else needs to be done to build locally.

---

So I have answered your question not by solving your direct problem, but giving you a more common/ canonical way of solving this problem that many developers have faced before.

Comment: thank you and while i appreciate your answer, the reason i have opted for environment variables is that i want to have one place to store my secrets and have them accessible for both android and ios